# Close popup on content click in jsImageBox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the [jsImageBox jquery plugin][1]. It allows one to make an image gallery. Anyone know how to close the image popup by clicking anywhere on the image instead of having to click the x on top right.
]: http://static.tumblr.com/qrevc1p/3FWlxvqbb/jsibox_basic.js

Comment: Why would a person need to scroll right? In the demo, the close button is always visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery on click behavior to close the image dialog.
If your images div is with id="images"

```
$("#images").click(function(){
    $("#images").hide(); // or change the element attribute which ever closes the div
});
```

Please share your code to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the code reveals that you can set your own methods of closing the image. Simply call the `jsiBoxClose()` function included in `jsibox_basic.js`.

Comment: how would one do this if the images are in a div but without any id ?

Comment: Give the div an ID or a class, then write a function like this:
`$('.myClass').on('click', function(){
     jsiBoxClose();
});`